# How to fix the background image so that it does not reduce on zooming out?

Tags: css, background, fixed

I want a fixed background image like [this](http://www.ghmhotels.com/en/ghm/home/#home).

Can this be made with only css without using any jQuery Plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 way: (ie9+ etc)

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

jQuery plugin cross-browser way:
http://bavotasan.com/2011/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/